# Point-free code is good. Why is mine slow? (performance)

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

Consider two lists

```
> plist = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
> qlist = [4, 6, 2]
```

And a comparison-type operation:

```
> all (\q -> all (\p -> fst p /= q) plist) qlist
False
```

After wracking my brains, I managed to come up with a version that doesn't involve lambdas (**EDITED**, thanks Willem Van Onsem):

```
> all (flip all plist . (. fst) . (/=)) qlist
False
```

Yet now my code runs ~30% slower. Why could this be? The memory profiles look identical (and healthy). I would imagine that these two should be equivalent.

On the other hand, the point-free version is so opaque here that it's probably hardly worth using to begin with.

Comment: How are you measuring the performance and what data are you measuring it on?

Comment: Performance meaning time, in seconds. My application is a chess engine. For the real thing you can see lines 65-82 of https://github.com/benediamond/Drais/blob/master/Main.hs

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Compiling with `ghc -O2` they run identically for me. Here's the benchmarking code: https://gist.github.com/jozefg/297eb0b19deda396798bc0093679d17b

Comment: You can remove the last flip, since `/=` is associative: `flip all plist . (. fst) . (/=)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For performance questions this will be two little programs which illustrate the difference in run times / ressource consumption.

Comment: All performance aside: “Point-free code is good” is, in general, a nonsense statement. Point-free is _sometimes more readable_ because it's simply more concise, but as soon as you need to use `flip` you're clearly beyond the line and should reconsider. The exception is if you're trying to generalise something from **Hask** to some more general category, i.e. not actually working with functions but other morphisms/arrows that can _only_ be written point-free – but then you don't have `flip` anyway.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations? Without? Or did you just run it with `ghci`/`runghc`? What version of GHC?

Comment: ghc --version The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2  
ghc -O2 --make Main.hs -prof -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp  
time ./Main ___ ___ +RTS -p Thanks to all.